# Arquillian weld embedded container - cannot run cdi tests (arq-weld-ee-embedded)

Tags: maven, jboss-weld, jboss-arquillian

For some reason I'm not able to run basic CDI tests using weld-ee-embedded container. I have 3 profiles set up, one is jboss as 7 managed, second is the jboss as 7 remote and the third is weld-ee-embedded. The first two work flawlessly, the third one doesn't and it throws exception out of nowhere:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/sql/ORAData
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.weld.ee.embedded_1_1.Utils.findBeanClasses(Utils.java:158)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.weld.ee.embedded_1_1.WeldEEMockContainer.deploy(WeldEEMockContainer.java:93)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:156)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:123)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:266)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deploy(ContainerDeployController.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createDeploymentContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.DeploymentExceptionHandler.verifyExpectedExceptionDuringDeploy(DeploymentExceptionHandler.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:79)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:258)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachManagedDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:234)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deployManaged(ContainerDeployController.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:182)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:202)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.sql.ORAData
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 113 more
```

I'm not using anything with oracle classes, drivers, configurations, nothing. Checked maven dependency tree, no 'oracle' there either. Really strange.

I thought first that it has something to do with arquillian-persistence-extension I'm using but I tried with simple @Named hello world type of bean and all I got is ORAData stuff.

My pom profile for weld-ee-embeded looks like this:

```
<profile>
            <id>arq-weld-ee-embedded</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.CR7</version>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
                    <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
                    <artifactId>weld-api</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
```

where 'arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1' has a version = 1.0.0.CR3

Answer (score 1):

Note - I can't provide a precise and specific answer because I'm not sure if I have all the info to do so, and specifically info about the contents of your archive, so this answer is a guess at best.

This looks like you have defined a ShrinkWrap archive in your `@Deployment`, with one of the classes in the deployment referencing the `oracle.sql.ORAData` class. Going by the sources of the Weld-EE embedded container for Arquillian, it appears that the Weld-EE container expects to be able to load all the classes in the archive, and in the nested archives. You might therefore, want to find out this offending class, and add the dependency (probably the Oracle JDBC driver) as a test-scoped one.

Note that the Weld-EE container only loads the classes, it does not create instances of them at this point. But, this does not mean that your tests would succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that arquillian-persistence extension just doesn't work with embedded weld container. You would have to use managed or remote type to take advantage of this extension.